# pv process interupting password

Tags: command-line, sd-card, dd, pipe

So I'm trying to flash an SD card with a 7GB image and it's taking forever (like 15 hours plus), so I decided to set up `pv` so I could see the progress. The problem I'm running into is that as soon as I enter the command, the progress report pops up, getting in the way of the password prompt so I can't continue with the transfer. How do I fix this?

Here's the code I've been using.

First I tried this:

```
sudo dd if=diskimage.img | pv -s 7340M | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=64k
```

As soon as I hit enter the progress pops up, so the password prompt is filled with that text. I was wondering if it has to do with using sudo `dd` for the output side, since I don't have to do that when not using `pv`, but all the examples I've seen do it.

Then I tried leaving out the size modifier, but it still happened. Finally I gave up and just went back to using `dd` without `pv`, and just checking the progress using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>, but I'd really like to get `pv` working.

Any and all help is appreciated.

On a side note, when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> these are the results I'm getting. (the load is from using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>)

```
sudo dd if=diskimage.img of=/dev/disk2 bs=64k

load: 1.09  cmd: dd 906 uninterruptible 0.00u 0.17s
176+0 records in
175+0 records out
11468800 bytes transferred in 37.236996 secs (307995 bytes/sec)

load: 0.60  cmd: dd 906 uninterruptible 0.01u 3.92s
4573+0 records in
4572+0 records out
299630592 bytes transferred in 2322.619605 secs (129005 bytes/sec)
```

Comment: You probably don't need `sudo` for the first `dd` which is only reading the source file. That should work with normal user privileges unless you have set up weird permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to that is pretty simple, become root before you run the command, because sudo is not carried through pipes anyways. So your solution is this:

```
# become root
sudo su
# do your stuff
dd if=diskimage.img | pv -s 7340M | dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=64k
# get back to your normal user account
exit
```

Comment: You're welcome, in the most cases we don't think the obvious easy way :)

Comment: I think using `sudo bash ...` as shown in heemayl's answer should be preferred over root shells (`sudo su` or similar) in general.

Answer (score 1):

As the commands around pipes start at the same time, your two `sudo dd` and `pv` all are starting simultaneously.

Two `sudo dd` are asking for password and `pv` is starting to pull its trigger too, all at the same time hence the prompt is turning into a garbage.

To solve this, you can use `bash` command grouping and use `sudo` on `bash` only:

```
sudo bash -c '{ dd if=diskimage.img | pv -s 7340M | dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=64K ;}'
```

Or use a subshell:

```
sudo bash -c '( dd if=diskimage.img | pv -s 7340M | dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=64K )'
```

In both cases, you will be prompted `sudo` password once and no other form of user switching is required too.